# Will my late 2012 macbook pro - 2.6 i7, 750gb HD, 16gb ram be fast enough for Yosemite?

Tags: upgrade, macos

My late 2012 macbook pro - 2.6 i7, 750gb HD, 16gb ram OSX 10.9.5 has been running very slow of late.

Ive been trying to trouble shoot the issue for a while now, but together with the time spent trouble shooting and the time spent while the machine is running slow ( can take up to 20 - 30 mins to awake and be usable from sleep).

Comment: I don't know who started all thIs "Yosemite will reduce your Mac to a crawl" nonsense, but it's ridiculous. I wish I had a MacBook as nice as yours, as I have a 2009 MacBook Pro (2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 4 GB of RAM, and a 260 GB Intel SSD) and even it runs Yosemite like a champ, and due to performance enhancements in El Capitan, and likely will run the next version even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Mac should have zero issues running Mavericks, Yosemite or (when it comes out) El Cap. it's a fast system with gobs of RAM and a nice big drive.

The sluggishness could be from a variety of sources but if you want to go ahead with a backup, wipe and restore that would be a good way to continue with your troubleshooting.

Comment: I agree with Steve. Make a backup then try a clean install. If you see slowness there, use activity monitor to capture the details of what is running. Also, look for io errors, a failing hard drive requires near constant backups and will slow down a Mac greatly.

Comment: My bad im actually already on Mavericks 10.9.5 and looking to upgrade to 10.10 (Yosemite) - ive updated the question title

Comment: Answer covers Yosemite and El Cap. Go for it!